# How to solve inequalities with more than one absolute value expression

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

There are two parts to this question.
1. I'm seeing the correct method to solve these types of inequalities as something to do with "transition points". **I don't quite understand this method. How do we find the specific inequalities, and how do we work with the boundaries once we set them?**

2. I personally thought of a more systematic approach: Simplify one absolute value expression (convert to positive/negative cases), then, for each of those cases, split the second expression to get a total of 4 cases. Then, I string together the inequalities that I get after solving them all, via union or intersection as the inequality sign marks.

*Edit: I've noticed the mistake in my process. In the Case 2 line, I forgot to switch the inequality sign. Still, I'm wondering why this isn't a viable strategy for solving these types of inequalities. **Why is this method inferior to the method described in (1)?***

Example problem:
|x-3|+|2x+5| > 6
|x-3| > 6-|2x+5|
Case 1: x-3 > 6-|2x+5|
|2x+5| > 9-x
Case 1a: 2x+5 > 9-x, 3x > 4, x > 4/3
Case 1b: 2x+5 < x-9, x < -14
Case 2: x-3 > |2x+5|-6
|2x+5| < x+3
Case 2a: 2x+5 < x+3, x < -2,
Case 2b: 2x+5 < -x-3, 3x < -8, x > -8/3

String together the 4 resulting inequalities:
((x < 4/3)U(x < -14))U((x < -2)U(x > -8/3))
So my answer would be x < -2 U x > -8/3
This is wrong. The answer would actually be x < -8/3 U x > -2.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I didn't check the whole thing, but I notice one mistake in Case 2—the inequality sign is pointing the wrong way.

Comment: Indeed. I covered that in my edit.

Comment: The systematic approach you describe in step 2 *is* totally workable, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

We need to rewrite the inequation without using the absolute value. Let's recall the definition of the absolute value:
$$
  \lvert x \rvert = 
  \begin{cases}
     -x & \text{if $x < 0$,} \\
      x & \text{if $x \geq 0$.}
  \end{cases}
$$
The transition points are the solutions of the equations $x-3 = 0$ and $2x+5 = 0$. It can be covenient to use a table like this one.

$$
\begin{array}{r|cccccccc}
  x                     & -\infty &       & -5/2 &      & 3 &      & +\infty\\
  \text{sign of $x-3$}  &         &  -    &      & -    &   & +    &        \\
  \lvert x-3 \rvert     &         & -x+3  &      & -x+3 &   & x-3  &        \\
  \text{sign of $2x+5$} &         &   -   &      & +    &   & +    &        \\
  \lvert 2x+5 \rvert    &         & -2x-5 &      & 2x+5 &   & 2x+5 &        \\
  \lvert x-3 \rvert + \lvert 2x+5 \rvert > 6 &         & -3x-2 > 6 &    & x+8 > 6  &   & 3x+2 > 6 &        \\ 
  \text{Solutions}     &         & x<-8/3&      & x>-2 &   & x > 4/3 & & \\   
\end{array}
$$
The set of solutions of the inequation is $(-\infty, -8/3] \cup (-2,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

We know for real $y,$

$|y|=+y$ if $y\ge0$ else  $|y|=-y$

Check  for $x\ge3; -\dfrac52\le x<3; x< -\dfrac52$